# NoClassDefFoundError Fop Library when deployed in Prod Server - Jdeveloper 11 Oracle ADF

Tags: noclassdeffounderror, oracle-adf, jdeveloper, apache-fop

Oracle Jdeveloper (Version 11.1.1.6.0) building ADF application that generate PDF file using Apache FOP Library. My Application runs local web server. But when deploy in production server, below NoClassDefFoundError exception is showing and failing to generate PDF file.

[image: Application Navigator Panel]
[image: Error Dialog when ADF Button clicked to generate PDF]

Exception output:

```xml
<code>
javax.el.ELException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/avalon/framework/configuration/ConfigurationException
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:191)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:297)
    ...
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/avalon/framework/configuration/ConfigurationException
    at org.apache.fop.apps.FopFactory.<init>(FopFactory.java:153)
    at org.apache.fop.apps.FopFactory.newInstance(FopFactory.java:177)
    ...
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.avalon.framework.configuration.ConfigurationException
    ...
    ...
</code>
```

Answer (score 2):

A NoClassDefFoundError with a caused by ClassNoFoundException points to a missing library on the server. Have you checked your deployment artifact (the EAR) if it contains all the needed FOP jars?
If all jars are part of the EAR (or better the WAR inside the EAR), you need to tell the Weblogic Server to load the jars from your deployment first before looking into jars already on the server. See https://tompeez.wordpress.com/2015/06/06/pitfalls-when-using-newer-versioned-libraries-than-shipped-with-jdeveloper-or-weblogic-server/ for more info on that.